# Is casting a pointer to const pointer and cast back to the original type undefined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, const-cast

I know casting a const pointer to non-const type might be undefined behavior, but what if the pointer is originally not const?

```
int i = 0;
int * pi = &i;
const int * const_pi = const_cast<const int*>(pi);
int * non_const_pi = const_cast<int*>(const_pi);
*non_const_pi = 0;
*non_const_pi = 1;
int j = *non_const_pi;
```

Is there's any undefined behavior? If any, where do they happen? May the compiler assume that `non_const_pi` is casted from a const pointer and perform no modification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not UB. Only when trying to modify a `const` object through a non-const access path results in UB. For this case, `non_const_pi` is pointing to a non-const object `i` in fact, then modifying through it is fine.

There's an exact example in the standard, [[dcl.type.cv]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4):

> ... any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr],
>   [expr.pre.incr]) a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its
>   lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior. [ Example:
>
> ```
> ...
>
> int i = 2;                              // not cv-qualified
> const int* cip;                         // pointer to const int
> cip = &i;                               // OK: cv-qualified access path to unqualified
> *cip = 4;                               // ill-formed: attempt to modify through ptr to const
>
> int* ip;
> ip = const_cast<int*>(cip);             // cast needed to convert const int* to int*
> *ip = 4;                                // defined: *ip points to i, a non-const object
> ```

Answer (score 6):

> I know casting a const pointer to non-const type might be undefined behavior.

That is a misunderstanding.

Const-casting pointers is never cause for undefined behavior. Dereferencing a non-`const` pointer obtained by way of `const_cast`-ing a `const` pointer to a `const` object is not undefined behavior either if the original object is used in read-only mode. It is undefined behavior if you try to write to the object.

```
int const i = 10;
int const* p1 = &i;
int* p2 = const_cast<int*>(p1);  // OK.
std::cout << *p2;                // Still OK.
*p2 = 20;                        // Not OK.
```

Given that, your second block of code is perfectly OK. There is no undefined behavior since the original object is a non-`const` object.

From [The Standard, Section 5.2.11, Expressions/Const cast](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const.cast#3) :

> The result of a pointer `const_cast` refers to the original object.

Comment: @supercat, I meant to say "const-casting" not just "casting".