# Where, specifically, does the standard state that modifying a const object is undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, object, language-lawyer, constants

The following example is well known to exhibit undefined behaviour:

```
T const x = T();
T& r = any_suitable_conversion_to_Tref(x); // fine
r = T(); // UB
```

This is confirmed for `const_cast` by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast):

> const_cast makes it possible to form a reference or pointer to non-const type that is actually referring to a const object or a reference or pointer to non-volatile type that is actually referring to a volatile object. Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.

However, it says nothing about e.g. c-style conversions and it doesn't quote the standard (cppreference generally never does).

Where exactly does the C++ standard forbid this?

Comment: Related: [Is casting a pointer to const pointer and cast back to the original type undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55428187/430766)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++17 standard states in chapter 10 "Declarations" under [**[dcl.type.cv]** 10.1.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#subsubsection.10.1.7.1):

> 4. Except that any class member declared `mutable` (10.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const` object during its lifetime (6.8) results in undefined behavior.